# How to train data in Azure (like Google Prediction API)

Tags: azure

I know there is Google Prediction API, on which everything is done and we just need to give a training model to train (https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/sentiment_analysis) but I need to know if there is a way to make the same thing in Microsoft Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Azure itself doesn't offer a Prediction API, it would only come through a 3rd party application through the Azure DataMarket - http://datamarket.azure.com

I know Microsoft has been doing work in the predictive AI scene but I also don't know of any API you can call that is similar to Google Prediction API.

Comment: Are there any way to make my own prediction API in Azure

Answer (score 1):

Azure now has a machine learning feature (in preview at the time of writing), more info here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/machine-learning/